# How to install pycurl for Python3.3 on Windows?

Tags: curl, python-3.3, pycurl

I'm a new python user, and I'd like to use `pycurl`.

Unfortunately, I can't find how to install it for python 3.3 on Windows (XP/32bits)
I tried to use pycurl bin from the official sites, but the launcher can't find python 2.6, that's right, I've the 3.3

Is there a method to install pycurl for python 3.3?